# Arduino Bluetooth Module HC-06 Error

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm having trouble getting my bluetooth module for my Arduino Uno working. I have followed the instructions from this website: 
http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-AND-Bluetooth-HC-05-Connecting-easily/?ALLSTEPS

So on my bluetooth settings it says COM7 Incoming so I put that in Putty and COM8 for outgoing so I put that in the arduino IDE. I get these errors

```
Sketch uses 3,016 bytes (9%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 226 bytes (11%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,822 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM8": Access is denied.


Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x31
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x31
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x31
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x31
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x31
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x31
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x31
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x31
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x31
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x31
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that "programmer is not responding" message because some other process is using the COM8 port. You can't program the Arduino through that port if some other program (like a serial terminal) is using the port, so exit the program, program the Arduino, and then open up the program again.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you trying to download your program via bluetooth, because if you are, don't, it won't work. If you are trying to upload the program using a usb cable make sure you are in that correct com port(NOT THE BLUETOOTH COM PORT). When uploading the program, keep the power and ground connected so it is still activated, but you need to disconnect the rx and tx connections(the two digital port connections). This is a common problem with the bluetooth modules because for some reason, when rx and tx are connected it interferes with the programs ability to upload.

Comment: It seemed like thats what the tutorial did. But okay, thanks! So when the program is uploaded can I disconnect it and leave it plugged into the battery? I'm also having trouble with the terminal. My bluetooth settings say COM7-incoming-hc06 and COM8-outgoing-hc06 'dev b'. What is the dev b and which port should I use for my terminal?

Comment: So once you have the program uploading properly you can connect rx and tx again. If you did that right then there should not be a problem connecting to your computer. Make sure that once the program is running you change the serial port to com8 (if your receiving information from your arduino) or com7(if you are sending instructions to the arduino) You could be getting these mixed up when pairing to your computer. I had these problems when using a hc-06 as well, it's a lot of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem, or the similar problem,  "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding",  is easily solved.

These problems occur if the Arduino is already wired to a breadboard with a HC-06 Bluetooth module.

First, unplug the Arduino from the power source and then remove the connections from the Arduino to the breadboard.  Power-up the Arduino and check the serial comm. port is correct.  Now uploading a sketch to the Arduino will occur without issues. Finally, unplug the power to the Arduino and then rewire the Arduino to the breadboard.

When the Bluetooth module is attached to the Arduino, the module prevents the Arduino's serial port from connecting to the USB from uploading sketches.